# Disable sticky keys

Tags: x11, accessibility

Sometimes my X behaves like it has «sticky keys» turned on. I have no idea how I activated it. Usually hitting the "sticky" key multiple times solves the problem, but it is nevertheless annoying.

I thought I had disabled sticky keys and other accessibility options with `xkbset -a`, but it still happens. Here are the relevant pieces from `xkbset q`:

```
Accessibility Features (AccessX) = Off
Sticky-Keys = Off
Two Keys Mask = On
Latch to Lock Mask = On
Slow-Keys = Off
Slow Keys Delay = 300
Bounce-Keys = Off
Debounce Delay = 300
AccessX Feedback = On
Use Fixed Pitch Bell = On
```

Any other places I should check?

I'm running Debian testing, xmonad window manager, and many gnome and kde applications. I suspect that it could be a gnome or kde feature.

Answer (score 2):

Mine did this too, sometimes. Everything would start doing unexpected things; mashing the meta keys a few times corrected the problem. It turns out I had a rubbish keyboard.

Are you sure you don't have an *actual* sticky key?

It doesn't have to *look* stuck. Sometimes it just seems to miss the key-up event.

Comment: This is an interesting theory. I wonder how I could check it next time this happens.

Comment: I've been thinking about this, and I can't come up with anything definitive. The problem is that, when it happens, you can't *do* anything to test it. Even mouse clicking is confused. It would need to be something that was running all the time, visible on screen, or writing to a log, just in case. Perhaps some key logging software (the kind people use to spy on others) might be useful?

Comment: It's very disappointing this answer was awarded bounty. I get this problem sporadically on my laptop both with and without an external keyboard. (one of the many external keyboards I have tried is a Leopold FC660M, i.e. not a rubbish keyboard)

Comment: The answer was never accepted; the bounty was awarded by default.

Comment: TBF, I've never reproduced the problem since I replaced that keyboard.

Answer (score 2):

Since Gnome 3.22, you can completely disable sticky keys, or adjust delay and speed, via Settings > Universal Access > Typing > Repeat Keys:

[image]